# How do i set relative layout background image from URL using Volley or something else?

Tags: android, url, layout

I want to set layout background image from web URL,

either using volley or Picasso or some else

is there any way to set this!

I found below code this from web but not working !!

```
Bitmap myImage = getBitmapFromURL("http://looksok.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/me.jpg");
RelativeLayout rLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

//BitmapDrawable(obj) convert Bitmap object into drawable object.
Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(myImage);
rLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);

public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this Android Smart Image View library.

http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/

Comment: this is for setting image for image view, I want to set image for layout, already am using volley in my project, if u know how to set relative layout bg from URL using volley please explain or else with other library also ok .. but I need to set image for relative layout

Comment: do u know how to give blur to that image ??

Answer (score 0):

I use the below link for set image from url:
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/211

Comment: do u know how to give blur to that image ??

Answer (score -1):

If you are using android studio then put `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'` in your `build.gradle` file and compile the project.

And then you can use Picasso library

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
    .load("http://looksok.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/me.jpg")
    .into(rLayout);
```

This will load image from given url into `rLayout`.

Reference : http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: do u know how to give blur to that image ??

Comment: @PrabhakarThota this is what I have used in my previous project to blur image https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript/

Comment: one more is there any way to give background image as blur like will give for tansperency #cc000000 like this

Comment: No it's not possible yet, you gotta edit a bitmap yourself as shown in the code I posted a link of

Comment: am new to this, am not getting how to do this, I tried it's not affecting. it's affecting only image once loaded from drawable, but in my case am loading image from URL that's the problem .. can you provide any code for this solution ??

Comment: you could try to overlay image with alpha =0 on your original image using Framelayout <Framelayout><YourImageview><BlurredImageview alpha = 0></Framelayout>

Comment: @Apurva I don't think that the into function accepts relative layout as an argument. It only accepts ImageView,RemoteViews or Target.